# Excel doesn't close on click, closes only on File-Close

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I've run into this problem after running some vba macros of mine.

I am unable to close Excel using the close (X) symbol. Even if I open a new instance of Excel (with no macro or file) the same issue persists.

The only way I can close it, is by clicking File->Close.

What is wrong here and how to fix it?

**EDIT**: The macros I run was pretty simple - it opened and closed the files, renamed it, took some data from it. I've run it many times before without any problems. Now I don't run it anymore, but the problem still stays.

Comment: I doubt we can answer this because you're runnig bespoke macros which may have affected the functionality. If you disable the macros can you close using the X? If so, you need to re-enable them one at a time until you find out which is causing the issue

Comment: @Dave Macros is already disabled. I edited the question.

Comment: Does the same issue occur with a new Excel file? If not, run another macro (just create something trivial). Test to see if that is the issue. Finally, copy the existing macro into the new workbook. See if the issue continues. If so, it's the code. If not, it's the workbook!

Comment: @Dave I'm not sure it's about the macro. Copying it to another workbook doesn't help. If a create a new workbook, open it and try to close it, only the File-closing works.

Comment: I don't understand your response. If you open a new instance of Excel, (a new file) can you close with the X?

Comment: @Dave No, I can't. I suspect some Excel settings are different now or something,

Comment: Then your issue has nothing to do with the Macro if that macro didn't affect any gloabl settings... What about ALT+F4 (shortcut to close)? Does that close Excel

Comment: I assume that this issue is only for Excel. If you open Word, it can close by clicking the X?

Comment: @Dave Yes, shortcut helps

Comment: @Dave It's weird, now that I tried the shorcut, the "X" closes file as well. The only remaining issue is that it asks for saving changes unnecessarily (I didn't change anything, so it shouldn't ask that).